# A non-convex box-constrained quadratic program

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization

I'm looking at the following (non-convex) quadratic program

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{x_1,\dots, x_n}{\text{minimize}} & a \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - b \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\\ \text{subject to} & \alpha_{\min} \leq \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \leq \alpha_{\max}\\ & \beta_{\min}\leq  x_i \leq \beta_{\max}, \quad \forall i=1,\dots, n\end{array}$$

with $a, b, \alpha_{\min}, \alpha_{\max}, \beta_{\min}, \beta_{\max} > 0$.

I don't really know where to start. The first term (not squared) is minimized for low $x_i$ while the second part is minimized for high $x_i$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what are the $q_i$? They are supposed to be functions of $x_i$... You should read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming

Comment: What is the sign of $b$?

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion. $q_i$ is $x_i$, and all coefficients (a, b, $\alpha$ and $\beta$) are strictly positive. I made edits to clarify.

Comment: You're right, I don't need that.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I agree with your edits. I reduced my original problem, where the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are a function of several other variables. I'm indifferent to any type of renaming of those. @pluton: also thanks for the Wikipedia link, but couldn't use it to solve it. It only seems to contain a solution for equality constraints.

Comment: Have you tried using the KKT conditions?

Comment: No not yet, but looks like a good approach. Will try! I only knew the Lagrange method which didn't help for this problem.

Comment: KKT is a good way to go, one minor comment: For intuition you can first ignore the constraints on $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$.  That results in separately minimizing $n$ concave functions of one variable over an interval, the answer to that modified problem is to have each $x_i^*$ as an endpoint of its interval.  If  $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^*$ just happens to be between $\alpha_{min}$ and $\alpha_{max}$ then you are done. (Else you need to do more work such as with KKT conditions).